# Finding Pathname for a file from Enviornment Variable in Linux using c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, environment-variables

So i am trying to create a Command Line Interpretor in Ubuntu using C/C++ 
It is part of our lab task for college
The basic feature of the CLI is to take input from the user , parse it to find the command and its arguments , then look up the pathname for the command from the Environment Variable
I have been able to parse the String , get the command and its arguments , I have also been able to read to the Path Environment Variables to get the directories of all the paths. Now i must look through these directories to find where the file (command) lies , and then return the complete path so it can be sent to execve for execution in the child process
i have to create a lookup function which takes the arguments array (the 0th index position contains the command name ) and the array of directories 
Here is an outline of the function that has been provided to us

```
// Search the directories identified by the dir argument to see
// if the argv[0] (the filename) appears there. Allocate a new
// string, place the full path name in it, then return the string.
//
char* lookupPath(char **argv, char **dir){
char* result;
char pName[MAX_PATH_LEN];
// check if is already an absolute path name
if( *argv[0] == '/' ) .....
// look in PATH directories, use access() to see if the
// file is in the dir
for( i = 0 ; i < MAX_PATHS ; i++ ) .....
// File name not found in any path variable
fprintf(stderr, "%s: command not found\n", argv[0]);
return NULL;
}
```

here argv is the array of arguments (0th index contains the command and the following index contains arguments)
and dir[] contains an array of all the directories

Now how em i suppose to traverse trough the directories to find the full path for the give command ?

Comment: Are you supposed to use C or C++?

Comment: Your code is wrong but you just have to think it through.  Presumably you have parsed PATH into each path that was separated by a colon into an array of strings (or vector if c++).  You are passing that array and the program name into the function so you can concat the pgm name onto each path and then use `access` to see if the file exists (mind your permissions with access).  The first one you find is the one you want otherwise it is an error if no file is found.

Comment: @Duck u basically got what i have to do, but can you help me out on how to accomplish it , i have not used access before , nor do i know how do i have to parse through each directory and look for the program
some links or a little code snippet that could tell me how to basically do it will be of great help

Comment: @CareyGregory we can use either c or c++ , We have been taught C++ through our entire course so we prefer c++ , our professor gave us the help code in c, so basically the program has turned into a mixture of c and c++ , i know this is not very efficient and well down right wrong , but due to lack of time i can not convert it all into c++ or either code in c

Comment: I think your professor made a mistake.  I think people should learn C first and C++ second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This more than I probably should have provided but there are enough things left you need to figure out that it isn't a slam dunk.

```
#include <unistd.h>

typedef std::vector<std::string> pathArray;

std::string lookupPath(const std::string pgm, pathArray &paths)
{
    int ret;

    for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); ++i)
    {
       std::string temp = paths[i];

       temp = temp + "/" + pgm;

       // let execv determine if it is executable
       // or you can do that here if required
       if ((ret = access(temp.c_str(), F_OK)) == 0) 
           return temp;
    }

    return("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pathArray pa;

    pa.push_back("/bin");
    pa.push_back("/usr/bin"); //and the rest of PATH contents

    std::string pgm;
    std::string fullpath;

    pgm = "ls";

    if ((fullpath = lookupPath(pgm, pa)) != "")
    {
        //execv(fullpath.c_str(), ....);
        //etc...
    }
    else
    {  //could not find pgm
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: great :D
this is great
Just a little question , like according to the file we are not just suppose to look into the complete path given , we are first suppose to look into the first directory , then if not found then go deeper and so on
like /usr/bin
so first suppose to look into usr , if not found there then go into usr/bin
so i guess the easiest way to do this is to parse the path string and break it into substring depending on "/"

Comment: and the line
    if ((ret = access(temp.c_str(), F_OK)) == 0) 
determines of the file exists in the path ?

Comment: Well that's not really how a shell PATH search works.  The whole point is to let users determine what order the PATH is searched depending on which comes first in the PATH string. But if that is the assignment then, yes, do it that way but in the real world it could break things.

Comment: Yes, F_OK check for existence.  Depending on your assignment you may want X_OK or some other combo of permissions.  I'll leave you to figure that out.

Comment: Just wanna say , Thanks a million , this was the part i was stuck on , after clearing this it took me another 2 hours or so to get the complete work down 
Now my CLI is working like a charm :D
Thanks alot bro

Comment: @user2557844 If the answer was helpful you should award points to the author by pressing the 'up' arrow.  If it was the best answer you should accept it by pressing the "check mark".